# If I connect my own SMTP server to wp_mail, reset password doesn't works anymore

Tags: wp-mail

I have decided to connect wp_mail to my "Gandi" authenticated SMTP server to improves the reliability of wp_mail, and avoids many potential problems (with gmail ...)

When I want to get a new password with the WP reset password form and click on the button "Get a new password", wordPress returns the error message "The e-mail could not be sent..."

If I comment my //add_action( 'phpmailer_init' ...)
The "Get a new password" form works again. I tried this with twentysixteen and no plugins activated.

Do someone have an idea why ?

This is my code:

```
add_action( 'phpmailer_init', array( &$this, 'prefix_send_smtp_email' ) , 10 );

public function prefix_send_smtp_email( PHPMailer $phpmailer ) {

    // Define that we are sending with SMTP
    $phpmailer->isSMTP();

    // The hostname of the mail server
    $phpmailer->Host = "mail.gandi.net";

    // Use SMTP authentication (true|false)
    $phpmailer->SMTPAuth = true;

    // SMTP port number - likely to be 25, 465 or 587
    $phpmailer->Port = "587";

    // Username to use for SMTP authentication
    $phpmailer->Username = "contact@xxx.com";

    // Password to use for SMTP authentication
    $phpmailer->Password = "xxxxxxxx";

    // Encryption system to use - ssl or tls
    $phpmailer->SMTPSecure = "tls";

    $phpmailer->From = "contact@xxx.com";
    $phpmailer->FromName = "Jhon Do";
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

A "$" character in my password seems to be guilty ...

Fix the issue by replacing:

```
$phpmailer->Password = "xxxxx$xx";
```

by

```
$phpmailer->Password = 'xxxxx$xx';
```